# Exclude copying duplicate values (Excel VBA)

Tags: vba, excel

I'm automating copying a certain HTML table to Excel then the duplicates must be deleted or be excluded in being copied. The code below, copy the values from html table to a certain cells then transpose/copy it again to another cells. But I cannot figure out the way on how to exclude duplicate values from being paste to the final cells.

There is a button wherein the copied value will be paste to excel. There are 10 rows in every html table.

code:

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub hand_over_Click()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim e, m, a As Integer, k As Variant

Range("XET1").Select
ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Format:="HTML", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:= _
    False, NoHTMLFormatting:=True

Columns("E").NumberFormat = "MMM DD YYYY  H:MM:SS AM/PM"
Columns("I").NumberFormat = "DDD"

e = 6
m = 1

While Not Range("C" & e) = ""
    e = e + 1
Wend

For a = 5 To 1000
    If ActiveSheet.Cells(a, 5).Value <> "" Then

        If Range("XEV" & m) <> "" Then
            Range("C" & e).Value = Range("XEU" & m).Value
            Range("F" & e).Value = Range("XFD" & m).Value
            k = Split(Split(Split(Range("XEV" & m).Value2, ") :")(1), "):")(0), " Req(")
            Range("E" & e) = DateValue(Mid(k(1), 5, 7) & Right(k(1), 4)) + TimeValue(Mid(k(1), 12, 8))
            Range("D" & e) = k(0)
            Range("I" & e).Value = Date

            e = e + 1
            m = m + 1
        End If

   End If
Next a

ActiveSheet.Range("XET1:XFD50").Clear
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

How about RemoveDuplicates before transpose/copy it..

```
Range("XET1:XFD50").Select
ActiveSheet.Range("XET1:XFD50").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11), Header:=xlY
```

Comment: Values per row in the HTML table is unique but duplicate checking is a must since there's a realtime update. So copying are being done realtime as well that's why I need the duplicate filter.